# How to send id to the webservice to retrieve the response in android?

Tags: android, web-services

I need to get a response from the server using the id.

I tried to send the request using following code:

```
    soapObj = new SoapObject(sNameSpace, sMethodName);
    soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapObj.addProperty("VideoID", 85);

    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObj);

    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(sUrl);
    http.debug = true;
```

but i am getting an exception that

```
11-22 11:37:16.012: WARN/System.err(554): SoapFault - faultcode:    
  'a:InternalServiceFault' faultstring: 'Specified argument was out of the range of 
  valid values.
  11-22 11:37:16.012: WARN/System.err(554): Parameter name: VideoID' faultactor: 'null'
 detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@44f67890
  11-22 11:37:16.012: WARN/System.err(554):     at
       org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:136)
11-22 11:37:16.022: WARN/System.err(554):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
11-22 11:37:16.022: WARN/System.err(554):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:96)
11-22 11:37:16.022: WARN/System.err(554):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:189)
11-22 11:37:16.022: WARN/System.err(554):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
11-22 11:37:16.022: WARN/System.err(554):     at com.utils.WsdlService.getResponse(WsdlService.java:57)
11-22 11:37:16.022: WARN/System.err(554):     at com.scopra.screens.TableOfContents.onCreate(TableOfContents.java:46)
11-22 11:37:16.022: WARN/System.err(554):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-22 11:37:16.022: WARN/System.err(554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-22 11:37:16.022: WARN/System.err(554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-22 11:37:16.022: WARN/System.err(554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-22 11:37:16.032: WARN/System.err(554):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-22 11:37:16.032: WARN/System.err(554):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 11:37:16.032: WARN/System.err(554):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-22 11:37:16.032: WARN/System.err(554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-22 11:37:16.032: WARN/System.err(554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 11:37:16.032: WARN/System.err(554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-22 11:37:16.032: WARN/System.err(554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-22 11:37:16.032: WARN/System.err(554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-22 11:37:16.032: WARN/System.err(554):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native      Method)
```

I dont whats the mistake.
Can anybody suggest help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL); try android HTTP transport instead of using HTTPTransportSE

Comment: @Karthi_heno yup, i tried...but getting null pointer exception...That means there was no data or what?

Comment: No proper response from service

Answer (score 0):

First find  ***SoapAction*** for desired operation (***sMethodName***) from WSDL.Then try this:

```
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("VideoID");
pi.setValue(85);
pi.setType(PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS);

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(sNameSpace, sMethodName);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
//Uncomment this line for .NET based Web Services:
//envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(sUrl);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
try
{
androidHttpTransport.call(SoapAction, envelope);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```