# how to retrieve the response using an Id in android?

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I want to retrieve the response from the web server using an id.
I need to send the id along with the namespace,method name, soap action and url, I dont know how to send this id with them using ksoap library.
Can anybody help me, what method we need to use for sending an id to request?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

check this:
[See Sharp Gears: Basic KSOAP Android Tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=basic%20ksoap%20android%20tutorial&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html&ei=GrbMTtu1K5GdOv-0sZwP&usg=AFQjCNFxvOY48M_pDWHamh0PpAprnhVmBg&cad=rja)
and **don't forget** it is not always true that:

```
SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
```

find SoapAction in WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shameless plug for another ksoap2-android tutorial.

http://www.shanekirk.com/2011/11/speaking-soap-with-android/

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7860887/841915). I am doing a similar thing. I am sending username and password to my SOAP web service. You can send the "ID" in that way.

Also, note this :

> request.addProperty("userid", user_id);
>
> request.addProperty("password",password);

This is used to add a request to your webservice. It should match with the column name of your database for successful results.

If you have any doubts please feel free to ask

Thanks

Comment: Hai Parth, I tried the same thing...but getting an exception that "the web server have taken my id as null" see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222800/how-to-send-id-to-the-webservice-to-retrieve-the-response-in-android

Comment: ok do one thing send me your web service code on androidparth@gmail.com..I will run it myself using my code and tell you soon. Is it a .asmx web service?

Comment: Hey hi I am sorry but I have never worked using WSDL before. I tried ur code using SOAP web service(.asmx) and it works fine. I created sample database having ID and password and depending upon ID, I retreive password from user